# Displaying thumbnails in google search results for flash games?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, sitemap, video-sitemap

Some sites are somehow displaying video preview thumbnails for pages that contain flash games in google search results. For example search for:

```
site:www.thorgaming.com game
```

I see this only on small sites which makes me believe google is not very happy about it.

How do they do it and is it ok with google?

I assume they are submitting thumbnails through [video sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80472), but I can't find any information about using them with flash games. I also run a few such sites through [rich snipped testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and it didn't detect any microdata tags on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Google is showing a thumbnail then of course Google is ok with it. Video sitemaps allow you to specify the location of a thumbnail and that includes for flash games.

According to this blog entry http://www.sharingmyopinion.com/2009/08/how-to-get-video-thumbnail-images-in.html

```
**Does Google show video thumbnails for any other sorts of files beside video?**

Yes. Google will also show video thumbnails for embedded "flash games". If you have a website dedicated to online flash games,
```

They may have submitted a sitemap in webmaster tools, one which doesn't have a common name that you could find.

Video sitemaps are not rich snippets.